# jQuery functions not working at all even though jQuery is loaded

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, boonex-dolphin

I have developed an extension for the Boonex Dolphin 7 CMS, the extension works ok on my server, but when I installed it on the clients server the jQuery functions stopped working.

I looked in the document head and I am seeing that jQuery is being loaded.
I also tried inserting the jQuery library within the extension and still nothing worked.

Their are other jQuery functions working fine on the website and on the same page while viewing my extension, but none of the jQuery functions that are apart from my extension that are also not working.

Any idea's as to why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a demo? sample code? a live page? If we can't see the problem, we can't fix it.

Comment: You should include some of the code so that we can try and help debug it (ie, why it might work in your environment, but not a production one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: http://css-plus.com/2010/03/6-steps-to-take-if-your-jquery-is-not-working/

One thing that I've missed quite a few times is the actual loading order of scripts. It works much like programming in general. A variable that hasn't been declared can't be used. It won't work.

Make sure your loading jQuery "above" all the other scripts depending on it. Also make sure jQuery actually loads at some point.

Most browser includes some sort of console. Simply type "jQuery" and you'll get the jQuery object returned if it's defined.

[image][image]

Comment: ^ This. If you get an `undefined`, check whether jQuery has been loaded into [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Dolphin Boonex uses its own jQuery and is not allowing to use another one. You have to find jQuery applications based on the version of jQuery used by your dolphin version. I believe it is jQuery 1.3.2 on Dolphin 7 (but it has to be verified).